# Deal with I/O capacities in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We are using the dynogels library to query a dynamoDB table. Unfortunately, as dynamoDB do not have a pagination feature, for a specific need, we are retrieving all data from the table through a loadAll to get all items of the table (18K items) and we are facing a error due to exceed of the I/O read capacity.

Except this query that retrieve all the content of the table, we only have very small read usage of the table. We also tried to dynamically update the I/O unity but we are limited to 4 changes/per hour.

Can you suggest as a solution? Do you know how to use the pagination in dynamodB ? is-it possible to use DAX as a local dynamoDB cache?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, as dynamoDB do not have a pagination feature, for a specific need,

DynamoDB does have pagination feature where you can specify the limit on number of pages to query and as part of the result, DynamoDB query / scan API returns a nextStartKey which can be used as the exclusiveStartKey to retrieve next, and do this until the nextStartKey is null which indicates the end of results: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination

Don't they have support of pagination in the dynogels library?

Comment: This is true. Indeed DynamoDB ONLY returns paginated query and  scan results. If you use the SDKs there are methods to hide the pagination (i.e. the SDKs will iterate the pages for you).